# Collection View Insert Item Weird Animation

Tags: swift, animation, uicollectionview

I have a messages collection view that is rotated 180 degrees (so that the cells are appended from the bottom).

```
collectionView?.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: (-(CGFloat)(Double.pi)))

cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi))
```

I want to use the insertItem option when appending new cells, but it causes the cells to perform an awkward animation where the ones visible on the screen are flipped upside down and over to the opposite side. However, when they are scrolled out of view and back into view, they reset into the right positions.

This is a video of the bug: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2X8FjOf5AqA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I fixed the issue by creating a UIView inside the custom collection view cell, and fitting all of the content (like the text bubble) inside that view then rotating the view by pi (instead of rotating the cell by pi). I still rotated the collection view using Bradley's answer above.

```
collectionView?.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi))
```

Comment: Not sure if it's a complete fix so I'm not gonna mark it as the answer until a few days later.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when `performBatchUpdates` is called when you add the new cell, all visible cells are re-rendered and the transform is applied *again*, essentially removing the transform.

You only want this to happen once, so the cells will maintain their transform. To do this, ensure the transform of the cells matches that of the `collectionView`, which we know won't change (because the collection view itself is not re-rendered on `performBatchUpdates`).

Also, you don't need to invert one of the transforms - a rotation by -π is equal to a rotation by π.

```
collectionView?.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi))

cell.transform = collectionView!.transform
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, totally makes sense now. However, the awkward animation is still occurring. I'm performing the cell transformation within the cellForRowAt function, should this code be somewhere else?